# How to set master detail/flow action bar to be opened from right to left in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have used master detail/flow in my android studio project as a new activity. Now, I need to change the direction of topic which is written inside the action bar (default is left to right) when its layout is opened. I have tried `android:supportsRtl="true"` in my AndroidManifest.xml (in application tag) but the direction did not change. Is there any other solution? In any case, thank you for your time.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. The `ActionBar` doesn't generally move horizontally. Please [edit] your question to better explain exactly what you're trying to do. I would mention, though, that the `supportsRtl` attribute by itself won't change your layouts' direction. You'd need to also use the appropriate attribute values that support RTL, and then set the `layoutDirection` to rtl in your layouts.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you. I edited the question. I need to change the direction of the topic which is written inside the action bar.